# how to get greatest prime number from 3 digits

Tags: java

I tried to get greatest prime number which is from 3 digits like from 100 to 999
but my code got me error

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i ,counter;
        //int arr[] = null;
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(counter=101 ; counter <999;counter++){
            boolean check = true ;
            for(i=2;i<counter;i++){             
                if(counter%i == 0){
                    check = false;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if(check){

                for(int index = 0;index<=arr.size();index++){
                    arr.add(counter);
                }
        }

        }


        System.out.println(arr.get(arr.size()-1));
        }
```

I Put numbers in array list and try to get last number index

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
    at Prime.main(Prime.java:23)
```

what's the problem ? and sorry for bad english

Comment: It seems to me that the `for` loop in the `if(check)` will result in an infinite loop. You can check that easily with the debugger.

Comment: Maybe the for loop that @ArnaudDenoyelle mentions should should be remove? But keep the statement that is inside the loop (ie `replace by arr.add(counter);`)

Comment: Shorter: `IntStream.iterate(999, n -> n - 1).filter(n -> IntStream.range(2, (int) Math.sqrt(n)).allMatch(k -> n % k != 0)).findFirst()`

Comment: @tobias_k Even faster, no need to check from 2 to n. Instead, you may check from 2 to n^1/2 only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is due to the following code segment.

```
for(int index = 0;index<=arr.size();index++){
    arr.add(counter);
}
```

It will loop indefinitely and results in adding so many objects in your array and hence OutOfMemory will occur.

I think this part doesn't need the for loop, i.e., change it to

```
arr.add(counter);
```

instead.

Comment: You don't even need the array; just store the latest value of `counter`.

Comment: why don't you start your for loop from 999 to 100 in this way you will find the  greatest prime number very fast than other answer,don't you agree

Comment: @shashi nice suggestion :) i will do that

Answer (score 3):

The second for loop is not necessary and keeps looping.
For the highest number start at 999 and count downwards.
Then the first result is the final one.

```
    for (int counter = 999; counter >= 100; --counter) {
        boolean check = true ;
        for (int i = 2; i < counter/2; i++) {             
            if (counter%i == 0) {
                check = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (check) {
            System.out.println(counter);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need the last `for`:

```
for(int index = 0;index<=arr.size();index++){
  arr.add(counter);
}
```

Instead of that, you can add your prime number:

```
if(check){
  arr.add(counter);
}
```

and print it outside:

```
for(int i = 0; i<arr.size(); i++){
  System.out.println(arr.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i, counter;
        Integer greatestPrime = null;
        //int arr[] = null;
        /*ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();*/
        for (counter = 101; counter < 999; counter++) {
            boolean isPrime = true;
            for (i = 2; i < counter; i++) {
                if (counter % i == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (isPrime) {
                /*for(int index = 0;index<=arr.size();index++){
                    arr.add(counter);
                }*/
                greatestPrime = counter;
            }

        }

        System.out.println(greatestPrime);
    }
```